# Compare keys from the same dict if contain same string python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have a dict with a lot of keys and about 100 values for those keys. 
But every dict have some sort of ID at the end, and I need to compare values of every dict with some reference, but just if they have the same id.
For example, keys:

```
{'mmc-1/bbc-1': {
'inner_key1' : '1',
'inner_key2' : '4',
'inner_key3' : '3',
'inner_key4' : '5',
'inner_key5' : '4',
'inner_key6' : '5',
'inner_key7' : '2',
'inner_key8' : '0',
'inner_key9' : '10'},
'mmc-1/bbc-2': {
'inner_key1' : '3',
'inner_key2' : '4',
'inner_key3' : '3',
'inner_key4' : '5',
'inner_key5' : '6',
'inner_key6' : '5',
'inner_key7' : '2',
'inner_key8' : '8',
'inner_key9' : '10'},
...
'mmc-2/bbc-1': {
'inner_key1' : '1',
'inner_key2' : '4',
'inner_key3' : '3',
'inner_key4' : '5',
'inner_key5' : '7',
'inner_key6' : '5',
'inner_key7' : '2',
'inner_key8' : '0',
'inner_key9' : '10'}}
```

So I need to compare just mmc-1/bbc-1 with mmc-2/bbc-1 and mmc-3/bbc-1, so, bbc ID is a condition. 
Remember, these are keys of dict. 
I can split keys with

```
.split('/')[1].split('-')[1]
```

But have no idea how to make a condition for comparing just dict with the same bbc. 
This is the code that compares and put differences into the new dict, but do it for every key, doesn't metter of bbc id, and that's what I need to change. 
objDict is my dict of objects, refd is dict with a reference object, let's take first objects from above example for ref object.

```
    #Choose reference object
ref = tempdict['mmc-1/bbc-1']
m_dif = {}

#Main function for finding differences
for obj, objDict in tempdict.iteritems():
    currentDict = {}

    # Check if the keys match.
    if objDict.keys() != ref.keys():
        for key in ref:
            if key not in objDict.keys():
                currentDict[key] = None

        for key in objDict:
            if key not in ref.keys():
                # Store unexpected values in object.
                currentDict[key] = None

    # Check if values are the same.
    for k, v in objDict.iteritems():
        # Check if the key is in ref to avoid error
        if k in ref:
            # Then compare if values are equal
            if ref[k] != objDict[k]:
                # Make actual diff
                currentDict[k] = v
    # Store differences for current object against object title.
    m_dif[obj] = currentDict
```

I know it's not a well-explained question, but let me know what is confusing, I'm going to explain.

Let's assume that reference is mmc-1/bbc-1 for objects with bbc id = 1.
Desired output:

```
{'mmc-2/bbc-1': {
'inner_key5' : '7'}}
```

And the same thing for all the others bbc id. This code works perfectly if there is just one ref for all objects, whatever bbc id is.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a subsample of each of your relevant objects - show us genuinely what all your `dict`s or whatever else looks like in Python syntax (I'm currently not entirely clear which bits are keys or values of what). Then provide a small sample of what the output should be like (and what you're struggling to do). This can often be a far simpler way to communicate problems than to use unfamiliar terminology.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I have edited my question a little.

Comment: give us something runnable that shows your problem (and preferably scale the problem back, there seems to be many more details here that are extraneous to your real issue...)

Comment: @thebjorn But I don't have more details, really. I've parsed xml file and got dict inside dict. And now I need to compare inner keys values of one outer key to other if they have the same bbc id. Of course, there are much more keys, but there is no need to type it here. You can maybe try to run script with those three keys and that code and see what I have already and how to make necessary changes.

Comment: So your goal is just to find all the keys `"mmc-i/bbc-1"` for all `i` from 0 to ~100? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @jovicbg your code isn't runnable (it has syntax errors), it has no input and produces no output. Do I need 10 inner keys to see your problem, if not then why do you have them in your question.  I shouldn't have to work this hard just to understand what you're asking and if I can answer your question.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen No, it's not. Compare values (inner_keys values) of one (that I took for reference) to all others with same bbc id. And difference put into new dict (like in desired output).

Comment: @thebjorn tempdict is the name of dict where all keys are stored, refd is the name of dict with reference key (object). I don't know what is error massage, but it works fine at me.

Comment: You must not be running the code in your question then, since the line under the comment saying `# Check if the keys match` can't possibly compile.

Comment: @thebjorn I understand you and help you anyway. But I don't know really how to provide any more details,, I know it's confusing.

Comment: @thebjorn Yes, that was coincidence error whale copying code here. I'm sorry.

Comment: @thebjorn I have pasted all over again my code

Comment: Is the problem that you want to somehow group together the keys with the same `bbc` value? So all the keys with `..bbc-1` and then the same for `..bbc-2` etc?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

To "group together the keys with the same bbc value" (which is my working interpretation of your question) there are a couple of things you could do:

```
import pprint

from collections import defaultdict

max_mmc = 10
max_bbc = 3

data = {"mmc-{}/bbc-{}".format(a, b): a * 10 ** b for a in range(max_mmc)
                                                  for b in range(max_bbc)}

pprint.pprint(data)

# approach where you already know the maximum id of bbc and mmc

result_1 = {"bbc-{}".format(bbc): [data["mmc-{}/bbc-{}".format(mmc, bbc)]
                                    for mmc in range(max_mmc)]
                                    for bbc in range(max_bbc)}

# approach where you don't know the maximums

result_2 = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in data.items(): # items because of Python 3
    mmc, bbc = k.split("/")
    result_2[bbc].append(v)

pprint.pprint(result_1)
pprint.pprint(result_2)
```

Here I've added a pretty short, borderline PEP-8 compliant mockup of your data - a subset of your keys are recreated, and each value is a crudely "hashed" version of the mmc and bbc. This allows us to later see that it has worked properly. (ie grouping according to bbc-2 should yield all multiples of 100). It also removes a lot of the clutter thebjorn was talking about.

The code contains two approaches - it will change depending on how much you know about the data. The first approach will be a lot more efficient. The code just produces a list of keys, as I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with them - however, this approach will still be applicable to whatever you want to do with the groups.

In both cases you can either immediately access the grouped value (`v` or `data[...]`) and modify it, or retroactively go through the list and do some more operations.

This has the following output:

```
{'mmc-0/bbc-0': 0,
 'mmc-0/bbc-1': 0,
 'mmc-0/bbc-2': 0,
 'mmc-1/bbc-0': 1,
 'mmc-1/bbc-1': 10,
 'mmc-1/bbc-2': 100,
 'mmc-2/bbc-0': 2,
 'mmc-2/bbc-1': 20,
 'mmc-2/bbc-2': 200,
 'mmc-3/bbc-0': 3,
 'mmc-3/bbc-1': 30,
 'mmc-3/bbc-2': 300,
 'mmc-4/bbc-0': 4,
 'mmc-4/bbc-1': 40,
 'mmc-4/bbc-2': 400,
 'mmc-5/bbc-0': 5,
 'mmc-5/bbc-1': 50,
 'mmc-5/bbc-2': 500,
 'mmc-6/bbc-0': 6,
 'mmc-6/bbc-1': 60,
 'mmc-6/bbc-2': 600,
 'mmc-7/bbc-0': 7,
 'mmc-7/bbc-1': 70,
 'mmc-7/bbc-2': 700,
 'mmc-8/bbc-0': 8,
 'mmc-8/bbc-1': 80,
 'mmc-8/bbc-2': 800,
 'mmc-9/bbc-0': 9,
 'mmc-9/bbc-1': 90,
 'mmc-9/bbc-2': 900}

{'bbc-0': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 'bbc-1': [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
 'bbc-2': [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]}

defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'bbc-0': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
             'bbc-1': [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
             'bbc-2': [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]})
```

We can see that the results have been correctly grouped in both cases. Note that you can use a defaultdict for anything you can use a dict for - it's just used for creating lists when a new key is met.

If you don't have access to the source of your data something like this will have to do. However, if you could change it at all, something like a nested dictionary/list (as the indices are contiguous) would make your life a lot easier.